# Read all messages from the very begining

Tags: rabbitmq

Consider a group chat scenario where 4 clients connect to a topic on an exchange. These clients each send an receive messages to the topic and as a result, they all send/receive messages from this topic.

Now imagine that a 5th client comes in and wants to read everything that was send from the beginning of time (as in, since the topic was first created and connected to).

Is there a built-in functionality in `RabbitMQ` to support this?

Many thanks,

**Edit:**

For clarification, what I'm really asking is whether or not `RabbitMQ` supports `SOW` since I was unable to find it on the documentations anywhere (http://devnull.crankuptheamps.com/documentation/html/develop/configuration/html/chapters/sow.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, the question is: *is there a way for RabbitMQ to output all messages having been sent to a topic upon a new subscriber joining?*

The short answer is **no.**

The long answer is *maybe*.  If all potential "participants" are known up-front, the participant queues can be set up and configured in advance, subscribed to the topic, and will collect all messages published to the topic (matching the routing key) while the server is running. Additional server configurations can yield queues that persist across server reboots.

Note that the original question/feature request as-described is inconsistent with RabbitMQ's architecture. RabbitMQ is supposed to be a transient storage node, where clients connect and disconnect at random. Messages dumped into queues are intended to be processed by only one message consumer, and once processed, the message broker's job is to forget about the message.

One other way of implementing such a functionality is to have an audit queue, where all published messages are distributed to the queue, and a writer service writes them all to an audit log somewhere (usually in a persistent data store or text file).  This would be something you would have to build, as there is currently no plug-in to automatically send messages out to a persistent storage (e.g. [Couchbase](https://www.couchbase.com), [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/)).

Alternatively, if used as a debug tool, there is the [Firehose](http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) plug-in. This is satisfactory when you are able to manually enable/disable it, but is not a good long-term solution as it will turn itself off upon any interruption of the broker.

Comment: Thanks! I did actually find this plugin (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-recent-history-exchange) that does more or less what I asked here but not quite what I expected. This question was more of a theoretical question since I wanted to find out if `RabbitMQ` supports `SOW` queries or not and clearly it doesn't. Many advanced queues (mostly not free) support this feature and it can be extremely useful since you won't have to rely on other mechanisms for storage of temporary data in a temp queue but that's besides the point. Many thanks for your reply though. It was very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help! With regard to the second part of your comment - it would be fairly trivial to add-on a product to deal with this scenario. I have to believe it would be more cost-effective than buying something, especially since most paid message brokers out there perform much worse than RMQ.

Answer (score 3):

What you would like to do is not a correct usage for RabbitMQ. Message Queues are **not** databases. They are not long term persistence solutions, like a RDBMS is. You can mainly use RabbitMQ as a *buffer* for processing incoming messages, which after the consumer handles it, get inserted into the database. When a new client connects to you service, the database will be read, not the message queue.

[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366178/840315)

Also, unless you are building a really big, highly scalable system, I doubt you actually need RabbitMQ.

Comment: With all due respect, this is incorrect. Many queue implementations support SOW (see http://devnull.crankuptheamps.com/documentation/html/develop/configuration/html/chapters/sow.html as an example). I was asking if rabbit implemented such a feature since I couldn't find anything in the documentations.

Comment: I don't know much about SOW, but I don't think many MQ implemented it. Generally, they are not used as a database, we have RDBS for that. I suggest you use RabbitMQ's mailing list here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka is the right solution for this use-case. "Log Compaction enabled topics" a.k.a. compacted topics are specifically designed for this usecase. But the catch is, obviously your messages have to be idempotent, strictly no delta-business. Because kafka will compact from time to time and may retain only the last message of a "key".